# Weird touch/click behaviour with jquery ui datepicker on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, angularjs, datepicker

I have an angular app with the following directive:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Simple date picker
 */
angular.module('twicketsApp').directive('twicketsDatePickerSimple', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            function initDatepicker() {
                element.click(function() {console.log('datepicker clicked');});
                element.datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                    changeMonth: false,
                    changeYear: false,
                    minDate: scope.futureOnly ? 0 : null,
                    maxDate: scope.futureOnly ? 365 : null,
                    onSelect: function (date) {
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(date); // update date value back to the model
                    },
                    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
                        inst.dpDiv.addClass('simple-date-panel');
                    }
                });
            }

            attrs.$observe('futureOnly', function (value) {
                scope.futureOnly = value === 'true' ? true : false; // attrs come in as a string
                initDatepicker();
            });

        }
    };
}]);
```

As you can see, there is both a click handler and a datepicker on this element (the click handler is just for debug).

When I **lightly** touch the element in safari in any iOS, the click handler fires - but the datepicker doesn't open. But if I press a little harder, the datepicker *does* open (this isn't a long press, as a long press doesn't fire the click handler or open the datepicker).

Absolutely no idea why this is happening. Any ideas?

My project uses fastclick, which may be having an affect.

Comment: Your phone is broken? Can you replicate this on another device or simulator?

Comment: On the iOS simulator, clicking doesn't work at all, but a long click (so some text near the input box is selected) followed by a click *does*. Weird. This is also the case with the iphone 4 (original test was iphone 5c)

Comment: What happens when you remove fastclick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with the following filthy hack, figured I could do it this way but was hoping there would be a better solution.

```
           ...

 function initDatepicker() {
    element.click(function() {element.datepicker( "show" );});
    element.datepicker({

           ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For mobile and touchable device or screens Jquery UI Datepicker initializes the datepicker component but never triggers the "show" method. Then you can use something like this:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker();

$(".datepicker").on("click", function () {
    $(this).datepicker("show");
});
```

Comment: Doesnt work. Cant get it to register the click at all